# e4x: filtering on subelement/attribute with dash?

Tags: javascript, predicate, e4x

Let's say we have this e4x snippet:

```
zoo = <zoo />;
zoo.animal += <animal animal-type='bear' name='Woofer' />;
zoo.animal += <animal animal-type='panda' name='Ling-Ling' />;
zoo.animal += <animal animal-type='seal' name='Arthur' />;
```

I can filter on names that begin with W or L:

```
js>zoo.animal.(@name.match(/^[WL]/))
<animal animal-type="bear" name="Woofer"/>
<animal animal-type="panda" name="Ling-Ling"/>
```

But how do I filter on animal types? The attribute "animal-type" has a dash in it so I can't use the @animal-type syntax, and the more general syntax ['@animal-type'] doesn't seem to work as a predicate selector.

Is there a way to select the current node in an e4x filtering predicate?

---

**update:** I got a hack to workaround in this case where I know all the elements have a "name" attribute:

```
js>zoo.animal.(@name.parent()['@animal-type'].match(/^[bp]/))
<animal animal-type="bear" name="Woofer"/>
<animal animal-type="panda" name="Ling-Ling"/>
```

But this wouldn't work in general.

---

**update 2:** Argh! So close:

```
f1=function(attr) { 
  var b = attr.match(/bear/) != null; 
  writeln(attr+":"+b); 
  return b;
}
f2=function(attr) { 
  var b = attr.match(/bear/) != null; 
  writeln(attr+":"+b); 
  return true;
}

js>zoo.*.(f1(@['animal-type']))
bear:true
panda:false
seal:false
js>zoo.*.(f2(@['animal-type']))
bear:true
panda:false
seal:false
<animal animal-type="bear" name="Woofer"/>
<animal animal-type="panda" name="Ling-Ling"/>
<animal animal-type="seal" name="Arthur"/>
```

WTF? I can access the `animal-type` attribute, and if I return an unconditional true, I can use a function as a filter predicate, but if I return the result of a comparison, it seems to ignore that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh -- the Javascript interpreter was in some weird state when I was running. Here's what works if I start from scratch:

```
zoo = <zoo />;
zoo.animal += <animal animal-type='bear' name='Woofer' />;
zoo.animal += <animal animal-type='panda' name='Ling-Ling' />;
zoo.animal += <animal animal-type='seal' name='Arthur' />;

js>zoo.animal.(@['animal-type'].match(/^[bp]/))
<animal animal-type="bear" name="Woofer"/>
<animal animal-type="panda" name="Ling-Ling"/>
js>zoo.animal.(@['animal-type'].match(/^[ps]/))
<animal animal-type="panda" name="Ling-Ling"/>
<animal animal-type="seal" name="Arthur"/>
```

I also have to be careful if it returns one result:

```
js>zoo.animal.(@['animal-type'].match(/^p/))
js>zoo.animal.(@['animal-type'].match(/^p/)).toXMLString()
<animal animal-type="panda" name="Ling-Ling"/>
```

XML nodes look "invisible" if they don't have any descendent elements or text content + you need to call toXMLString() to convert them to a string.